# How to solve "GC overhead limit exceeded" using maven jvmArg?

Tags: java, scala, maven, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

When running a class I have the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I've tried to increase the jvmArg heap size from inside maven pom.xml of the class package:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    (...)
</parent>


<artifactId>(...)</artifactId>
<name>(...)</name>

<properties>
    <javaOpts.Xmx>4g</javaOpts.Xmx> <!-- default that can be adjusted on the command line with -DjavaOpts.Xmx=... -->
    <(...).basedir>${project.basedir}/..</(...).basedir>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <launchers>
                    <launcher>
                        <id>MyClassName</id>
                        <mainClass>(...)</mainClass>
                        <jvmArgs>
                            <jvmArg>-Xmx${javaOpts.Xmx}</jvmArg>
                        (...)
```

I've tried the last cited line with many values:

- `<jvmArg>-Xmx512m{javaOpts.Xmx}</jvmArg>`
- `<jvmArg>-Xmx4096M{javaOpts.Xmx}</jvmArg>`
- ...
- `<jvmArg>-Xmx10000000000M{javaOpts.Xmx}</jvmArg>`

But for all of them I have the same error.

Anyone can help me?
Observation: I'm running from **IntelliJ IDEA**.

Comment: Maven has nothing to do with "running". If your problem is out of memory when RUNNING you application, you need to set the heap size params at launch time, not in maven at build time. If I misunderstood please update your question

Comment: I assume this is a type: ```<jvmArg>-Xmx512m{javaOpts.Xmx}</jvmArg>``` and you actually meant ```<jvmArg>-Xmx512m</jvmArg>```?

Answer (score 49):

**Java 7**

It's not a Maven issue, you need to give more memory to the VM. You do this via **environment variables**, and the Maven Launcher will automatically pick up these settings on load, and use them to configure the underlying Java VM.

The simple way to do it is to:

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -Xss128M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"`

Windows:

`set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -Xss128M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`

(No double quotes)

**Java 8**

Java 8 has replaced permanent generation with metaspace, and the new settings look like this:

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -Xss128M -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"`

Comment: This should be added to your shell environment, not your pom.xml.

Comment: Add "set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" line to your "mvn.bat" file as a first line of code. "mvn.bat" could be found at C:\MAVEN_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY\bin. If you are on Unix platform, you should edit mvn.sh instead of mvn.bat. You can change -Xms and -Xmx values, based on how much memory is required by your programs to run/compile/build.

Comment: FYI: the MaxPermSize option was removed in Java 8 and is now ignored.

Comment: @flavian there is mistake in your answer. I think you meant - startup memory assignment - Xms128m instead of -Xss128m - which is huuuuge stack size for each thread

Comment: It is a maven issue in my case. Failing after 30mins when it's normally done in 3mins.

Answer (score 10):

I had kind of the same problem: My project wokspace consists of >250 maven modules and when opening a `pom.xml` in IDEA, the `<project>` and `<parent>` tags were underlined in red and this error showed up, when hovering over the broken tags:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

**My solution**:

- set high values in `>Settings >Build, Execution, Deployment >Build Tools >Maven >Importing` - e.g. `-Xmx1g` **and**
- change the maven implementation under `>Settings >Build, Execution, Deployment >Build Tools >Maven` (Maven home directory) from `(Bundled) Maven 3` to my local maven installation (not the one bundled with IDEA), e.g. to `/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9`: [image: Maven Settings Screenshot]

Since I had problems with the bundled maven before, I just don't trust the bundled maven.

Comment: Adding a heap size option on the Maven:Importing screen (but keeping the bundled Maven 3) worked for me when trying to import the entire wildfly-swarm project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 7):

Adding parallel garbage collection to the top answer above is probably the best option:

```
-Xmx2048M -Xss128M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you may disable GC limit:

```
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Comment: Just to get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` in my case :-/

Comment: Disabling it will only delay the problem, not mitigate it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for very late response, but I think my answer might help other people as well.

scala-maven-plugin doesn't work with MAVEN_OPTS, the only way to increase memory is to use jvmArgs in the plugin configuration. But you should put jvmArgs not inside launcher section, but inside configuration section, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <jvmArgs>
        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
        <jvmArg>-Xms256m</jvmArg>
    </jvmArgs>
</configuration>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding jvmArgs to the [maven-scala-plugin](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/usage_run.html) config in your pom.xml.

What do you mean you are running from IntelliJ IDEA? How exactly are you doing that? Via their build/run you are not going via Maven at all! Then changing the maven-scala-plugin launchers in your pom.xml is basically useless. To change the run configurations for IntelliJ see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea).

If you really want to run from Maven, after you add the jvmArg params to the pom.xml, you then need to run the plugin:

```
mvm scala:run -Dlauncher=MyClassName
```

Note: where you put MyClassName, that is actually the name of the launcher, not the class. For many projects, people pick reasonable names for the launchers and that makes them often coincide with the local name of the classes. But you could call it MyLauncher if you wanted.

Reading maven-scala-plugin's docs might help you.

Comment: After make changes to the pom, I call mvn clean and mvn install from terminal. But use the IDEA Run button. Actually I want to use the Debug of IDEA to watch some variable and discover from where come an output mistake of the software. Which is not possible from terminal (as I know).

Comment: Using the mvn command that you said above from Terminal produce an error too.

Comment: did you try setting ```export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2G``` from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me. What did work was [this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003315120-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded) from Intellij support forum. It suggests increasing build process heap size to 1024 MB by going to **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Compiler** > **Build Process heap size(Mbytes)**