# Command line in IntelliJ, program arguments field in debug/configurations, how to structure them?

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea

I have a Java file that I run in the command line like like this:

```
Java program_file_name<input.txt>output.txt
```

The Scanner class in the Java file takes in a text file as input and I want it to produce a text file as output, pretty standard stuff.

I looked at the following page:
[How do you input commandline argument in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea)

and tried putting

```
<input.txt>output.txt
```

into the program arguments field in run/debug configurations. The output doesn't seem to be showing in the output.txt, it works fine in command line, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you do in command line is executing **shell command** which redirects input and output from/to a file. On the other hand java run/debug does not execute shell command but runs selected **class** with passed arguments. And what you do is that you pass it single argument `<input.txt>output.txt`. But it does not redirect anything.

What you can do is to modify your class that it accepts arguments - files to read / or write to. I have found one [IntelliJ plugin](https://github.com/raymi/opcplugin) that adds new debug configuration where it is possible to specify file to redirect input. But it is only one half of your request.

Comment: Very late reply, but yes, it's clear now, thank you :)