# Java cannot get environment variable (system property)

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I need that my code can get the environment variable when running test with IntelliJ:

```
private String sdkDir = System.getProperty("sdk.root");
```

The problem is that this is always `null`, I have set both in `bashrc` and also with `bash_profile` but not really works with Ubuntu.

`bashrc` and `bash_profile` both have this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/xybrek/zulu1.8.0_25-8.4.0.1-x86lx64
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dsdk.root=/home/xybrek/java-sdk-1.9.17"
export PATH=$PATH:/home/xybrek/zulu1.8.0_25-8.4.0.1-x86lx64/bin
export PATH
```

What could be missing with my configuration?

**Update:**

I cannot change the Java code: `System.getProperty("sdk.root");` as this is coming from a compiled Arquillian container I can't modify.

What I need would be a proper way of having this `System.getProperty` method to get the value.

Where to put this "sdk.root" for IntelliJ to pick it up? In a properties file or bash?

Comment: What is the exact Java command line you're running? It looks like you need to explicitly include `$JAVA_OPTIONS` in the command line invocation - the Java process won't automatically read that environment variable.

Comment: I am just doing right click then Run Test. Like typical manual JUnit test.

Comment: There must be a way of setting the command line options directly in some IntelliJ dialog, for running some specific Java app. Nothing to do with environment variables.

Comment: Check out: [How do you input commandline argument in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea), this is where you need to put `-Dsdk.root=something`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use

```
String val = System.getenv( "PATH" );
```

for the value of an environment variable. A property value has nothing to do with the Environment of a process.

```
String val = System.getProperty( "sdk.root");
```

is for properties.

There should be a way of setting command line arguments in the dialog for preparing the execution of a Java program in your IDE. This is where you should define -Dsdk.root=....

Comment: Why not System.getProperty ?

Comment: Check your IDE's features. In Eclipse, the run dialog has a tab for defining the environment and another one for command line options where you could put the -Dsdk.root=... literally. The environment variable will only work if some agent expands it in the command line calling java, the JVM.