# In IntelliJ, how do I pass command line variables when building with Maven (TestNG run configuration)?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to do the following, but in IntelliJ with a TestNG run configuration:

`mvn clean install -Dfoo=bar`

So, the value for the foo system property should be bar:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("foo"));
======
bar
```

All potential answers I've googled either tell me to hardcode variables into my pom.xml (which I can't do) or say to "[just set it in Edit Configurations...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea)" without showing what a properly set variable looks like. I dug through the IntelliJ manual too.

I tried all the logical names for "foo" in both Run/Debug Configurations/Parameters tab and Run/Debug Configurations/Environment Variables, such as *Dfoo* and *-Dfoo*.

[image: Run/Debug Configurations and Environment Variables]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Maven configuration instead of a TestNG configuration. You can still run your TestNG tests from the Maven configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, using a Maven configuration solved the problem. I was using a TestNG configuration. I edited your answer a little bit to provide more context for someone finding this page on Google.

Comment: Maybe you would also like [Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179)