# How to run IntelliJ IDEA with argument and redirect symbol <?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is a question which is different from

[How do you input commandline argument in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea)

The point of this question is, run with the **redirct symbol**

> **<**

So in command line I can do this

> java -cp /classpath MyClass < data.txt

which works good.

But I followed [**official help document**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-application.html) of Intellij and tried to put redirect symbol < in argument.

[image]

Intellij threw an

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**.

And I didn't find any illustration about using redirect symbol < with arguments in official help document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **Program Arguments** field, put in a path to the file, instead of the redirect symbol.

So if your IntelliJ project main directory is

```
/home/glenn/Proj_java/Algorithms/Chapter1/BinarySearch
```

and your file data.txt is in that directory, just put in this:

```
data.txt
```

If you had a subdirectory under that named "mystuff" which contained your file, in **Program Arguments** use the relative path to the file:

```
mystuff/data.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I do exactly know how to avoid redirect symbol "<" in your way, but what if I run the program with more than single argument and "<"?  For example $java BinarySearch WhiteList.txt < TotalList.txt , You can't avoid using "<" anymore now.

Comment: In IntelliJ you can pass multiple Program Arguments if you want. So in this case you might try passing this  
  
`WhiteList.txt   TotalList.txt`  

Then in your Java code do something like this inside main() to see the filenames passed as Program Arguments:  

`
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {  
            System.out.format("arg %d:  %s\n", i, args[i]);  
        };  
`  

You can grab the first filename with args[0] and the second with args[1]. Then in your Java code you can open and read from those files if you want.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ does not support redirect symbol for now. It's really painful~!

As a compromise, you could try:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\GDUT\\Dropbox\\Alg4\\test_data\\eval.txt");
System.setIn(fis);
```

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3153#tab=Comments