# Giving my program a txt file from the terminal using the args array

Tags: java, intellij-idea

im learning java and have some issues with opening a file when i try to input it from the terminal.
Currently my code looks a little like this but i have tried with scanner, file etc.

```
if(args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("No maze file inputed, exiting");
        System.exit(1);
    }
Reader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
```

When i compile i use "javac main.java test.txt" and i get the error message "Class names, 'test.txt', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested" 
 What am i doing wrong here?
(I want it to be a reader so i can send it into a method that takes a reader)

Comment: it should be `javac FileName.Java` then `java ClassName test.txt`

Comment: Intellij will compile the sources on its own you don't need to call javac.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Thanks alot guys, teacher did not go over how to compile in Java so gotten a bit confused, works now!

Comment: Also intellij should have a way to specify any runtime arguments. (I use eclipse, so no idea where that is in Intellij)