# Cannot debug Java app by passing args to main method

Tags: java, javac

I have the following java file in `C:\projects\com.company` folder:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //want to check the args parameters
    }
}
```

Then I try to run the following command in `C:\projects` directory:

```
java com.company.MyProgram C:\inputs\test.txt pro2 pro3
```

Then expect to get 3 parameters in the main method's args. However gives, "*Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.MyProgram*" error.

So, the questions:

**1.** What is the problem with this code or command?

**2.** How can I debug this code using IntelliJ and check the args after running `java com.company.MyProgram C:\inputs\test.txt pro2 pro3` command on cmd?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the Java file again? The current compiled file might be an older one which doesn't have a `main` method.

Comment: Do you mean build and then using the `out\production\...` directory?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, see if it works. I tried this code using an online Java compiler and it's working fine, maybe it's something related to compiling and stuff.

Comment: What about debug via cmd?

Comment: If you want to debug using Intellij, you can [add the command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2066307/9997212) and [debug normally](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html#general-procedure): it'll show the value of each argument inside the `args`. If you want to debug using the command-line, you can add [some command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/9997212) when running `java`.

Comment: 1. It could be because your folder structure should be "C:\projects\com\company" and not "C:\projects\com.company". 2. You have not compiled your source and the .class file is missing in that folder.