# How to read and write files from the command line in Java?

Tags: java

I have that code in Python, but I want to do the same thing in Java.

```
import sys

def main(args):
    # Showing the arguments of the program
    print("#ARGS = %i" %len((args)))
    print("PROGRAM = %s" %(args[0]))
    print("ARG1 = %s, ARG2 = %s" %(args[1], args[2]))
    # Open files
    input = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
    output = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
    # ...
    # Closing files
    input.close()
    output.close()
    # end of the program

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

The same code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Showing the arguments of the program
    printf("#ARGS = %i\n", argc);
    printf("PROGRAMA = %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("ARG1 = %s, ARG2 = %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    // Opening files
    FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE* output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    // ...
    // Closing files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    // End of the program
    return 0;
}
```

How can I create a code like that in Java? Is there a command like that "input = open(sys.argv[1],'r')" or  "FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r")" in Java?

Comment: The `main` method in a Java program has a `String[] args` parameter. Have you tried using that?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Scanner` to read from file, and use `PrintWriter` to write to a file.

```java
public class FileIo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (
                Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("anotherFileName.txt")
        ) {

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String str = in.nextLine();
                out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In java, the `try(resources) {}` block will automatically close its resources.

Use `args[0]` and `args[1]` to replace the in and out file name.

Comment: How to use the args[0] and args[1]?

Comment: In java, `args[0], args[0], ... ` is the command line arguments. Support your java run command is `java FileIo filename.txt anotherFileName.txt`, then the args[0] is 'filename.txt', and args[1] is 'anotherFileName.txt'. In IDE like IDEA, args is defined in the Run/Debug Configurations->Program arguments (see <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-command-line-arguments-in-intellij-idea>)

Answer (score -2):

#### java 9 or above

java provide repl env [what is repl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-repl) **jshell** since java version 9

```
C:\Users\User>jshell
| Welcome to JShell -- Version 9.0.4
| For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> Math.round(34.543)
$1 ==> 35
```

read/write file with FileReader/FileWriter example

```
jshell> import java.io.*;

jshell> BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/xxx/local/tempFiles/gids", true));
   ...> writer.write("appended text");
   ...> writer.close();
   ...>
writer ==> java.io.BufferedWriter@66a29884

jshell>

jshell> BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/xxx/local/tempFiles/gids"));
   ...> String currentLine = reader.readLine();
   ...> reader.close();
   ...>
reader ==> java.io.BufferedReader@17a7cec2
currentLine ==> "appended textappended text"

jshell> currentLine
currentLine ==> "appended textappended text"

jshell>
```

#### java 8

1. put a `while(true)` loop in main method, and get user input, and process things accordingly. For example, `q` for exit, `r /User/xxx/file` for read file '/User/xxx/file', and it is not great because you have to consider all the requirements and needs and it is set, you can not change the code at runtime.
2. [groovysh](https://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html), you can run java code in it

Comment: As of Java 9 there is indeed a [Java REPL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm), although I can't see anything in the question that relies on one.

Comment: 1. isn't true these days. In later JDKs. `jshell` is REPL tool and with certain source files you can use java launcher direct from source file:  `java xyz.java`

Comment: sorry about that, I should look more into it