# How to set log level to 'debug' when app is started in debug mode (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2, slf4j

When starting the app normally print only log.info(...) into the console. When starting the app in debug mode print log.info(...) and log.debug(...).
Can I set the debug level without reading system properties in the main method?

```
@Slf4j
public class Logging {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("This message should be logged when running the app normally");
        log.debug("This message should be logged when running the app in debug mode");
    }

}
```

Configuration file (log4j2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 'status' defines the log level of the internal log4j events -->
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applications should not be aware if they are running in debug or not. Instead use a different command line argument (for Intellij: [How do you input command line arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-command-line-arguments-in-intellij-idea)) and then set the log level programmatically in the code (see answer [Programmatically change log level in Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434252/programmatically-change-log-level-in-log4j2)).